# Second Derivative of a Polar Coordinate

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

https://snag.gy/buiJve.jpg

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I've calculated this several times and have been unable to produce the correct answer. I have followed the procedures.

I went to calculate the second Derivative using the equation

```
    d/dt(dy/dx)/(dx/dt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did, the first derivative is found by

$$y'(t)=\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}},$$

where the "$'$" is **derivative with respect to x**.

Same thing for the second derivative:

$$y''(t)=\frac{dy'}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy'}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}.$$

I get

> $$\frac{2t}{(t+1)^3}$$

Comment: Unfortunately, That does not seem to be the correct answer. Given that we're calculating for the second derivative of the polar coordinate system we have to use the equation d^2(y)/d^2(x) = (d/dt(dy/dx))/(dx/dt)

Comment: Sorry, I made a stupid mistake. I get the same as you. Now there is a "dt" in your answer

Comment: Thanks, that's right! Where did the t on top come from?

Comment: From $\frac{1}{dx/dt}=\frac{t}{1+t}$